# Best way to wait until a condition is true

Tags: c#, winforms

I want program to wait when a variable come from plc. I have tried a algorithm with while but the application is breaking. the code is below. how to do this without while loop in c# ?

```
   `private void toolStripButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
        ModbusIpMaster master = ModbusIpMaster.CreateIp(client);
        client.Connect("192.168.0.1", 502);

        ushort[] offsets = new ushort[4];
        for (int j = 0; j < a; j++)
        {
            string[] numbers = Regex.Split(coordinateLabel[j].Text, @"\D+");
            int index = 0;
            foreach (string value in numbers)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                {
                    int i = int.Parse(value);
                    offsets[index] = (ushort)(i);
                    index++;
                }
            }
            master.WriteSingleRegister(0, offsets[1]);
            master.WriteSingleRegister(1, offsets[2]);
            master.WriteSingleRegister(2, (ushort)(variable_Z[j]));
            while (true)
            {
                offsets = master.ReadHoldingRegisters(0, 4);
                if (offsets[3] == 1)
                {
                    master.WriteSingleRegister(0, 0);
                    master.WriteSingleRegister(1, 0);
                    master.WriteSingleRegister(2, 0);
                    while (true)
                    {
                        offsets = master.ReadHoldingRegisters(0, 4);
                        if (offsets[3] == 0)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        client.Close();
    }`
```

Comment: `but the application is breaking.` In what way is it breaking?

Comment: when the program enters the loop to wait for the data comes from PLC, application breaks if it waits for a long time @mjwills

Comment: You're almost certainly going to need to have a loop because you need to poll the PLC. It's possible but unlikely that the PLC can push an event over to you to handle. It is probably "breaking" because it's polling the thing constantly and leaving no time to do anything else. You may be able to use async/await and Task.Delay to resolve that. Or if you're very lazy and don't want to address it properly, you might throw an Application.DoEvents in that loop.

Comment: The value called PLC indicates whether the robot's hand is opened or closed. I'm sending offsets to the x, y, and z axes where the robots will go based on whether the hand is open or closed. I do not know at what intervals the robot can go. So I do not want to use delay. @MineR

Comment: Well experiment - put a Thread.Sleep for 10ms in the loop and see what happens.

Comment: the application is in break mode again @MineR

Comment: Without a Thread.Sleep the OS will determine your application is not responding, and will react accordingly. I would put the while loop inside its own thread and put a short Thread.Sleep(10); inside it

Answer (score 2):

Some advices:

- Move the implementation inside click event handler to another method/class (read something about [SOLID](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) principles)
- Make the method that checks for the PLC asyncronous , so you dont block the main thread and you don't get that error you are telling about.

--

```
public class PlcChecker
{
   TcpClient client {get;set;}
   ModbusIpMaster master{get;set;}

   public PlcChecker()
   {
      client= new TcpClient();
    }

    public async Task Connect(string ip,int port)
    {
      ModbusIpMaster master = ModbusIpMaster.CreateIp(client);
      client.Connect(ip,port);
    }

     public async Task<bool> Check()
     {
       //your code to call master and while(true)
     }

}

 public class YourWinForm
{
    public PlcChecker plcChekcer { get; private set; }

    private async void toolStripButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        plcChekcer = new PlcChecker();
        await plcChekcer.Connect("192.168.0.1", 502);
        bool result = await plcChekcer.Check();
        if(result)
        {
             //do something   
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Firstly thanks for your help. there are two while loop. they are nested each other. offsets[3] is for chacking whether gripper is opened or not. firs of loops is checking that the robot has taken the product from home point. when it is true, I send offset of the point where the robot should place the product palette and the code enter second while loop. this loop is checking that robot went palet and put the product. when it is true, I send offsets of home point and both of loops is breaked. can the code you writed handle  it ? and check method of PlcChecker class give an error. why? @badulake

Comment: I think your blocking problem is that you are blocking main thread with a infinite loop. If you use this approach you will run the code in another thread so you won't block the app

Comment: You could consider separate the 2 loops into 2 separate methods. You dont need to nest one inside the other

Comment: ok thanks I will try. wyh the check method give build error? @badulake

Comment: My code is pseudocode. Please give upvote if you want